# How to read Keras's model structure?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

For example:

```
BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
     BATCH_SIZE = 64
    train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, tf.compat.v1.data.get_output_shapes(train_dataset))
test_dataset = test_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, tf.compat.v1.data.get_output_shapes(test_dataset))

def pad_to_size(vec, size):
  zeros = [0] * (size - len(vec))
  vec.extend(zeros)
  return vec
...

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(encoder.vocab_size, 64),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

print(model.summary())
```

The print reads as:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, None, 64)          523840    
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 128)               66048     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 598,209
Trainable params: 598,209
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I have the following question:

1) For the embedding layer, why is the ouput shape is `(None, None, 64)`. I understand '64' is the vector length. Why are the *other two None*?

2) How is the output shape of bidirectional layer is `(None, 128)`? Why is it `128`?

Answer (score 1):

> For the embedding layer, why is the ouput shape is (None, None, 64). I understand '64' is the vector length. Why are the other two None?

You can see [this function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L1753) produces `(None,None)` (including the batch dimension) (in other words it does `input_shape=(None,)` as default) if you don't define the `input_shape` to the first layer of the Sequential model.

If you pass in an input tensor of size `(None, None)` to an embedding layer, it produces a `(None, None, 64)` tensor assuming embedding dimension is 64. The first `None` is the batch dimension and the second is the time dimension (refers to the `input_length` parameter). So that's why you get a `(None, None, 64)` sized output.

> How is the output shape of bidirectional layer is (None, 128)? Why is it 128?

Here, you have a `Bidirectional` LSTM. Your `LSTM` layer produces a `(None, 64)` sized output (when `return_sequences=False`). When you have  a `Bidirectional` layer it is like having two `LSTM` layers (one going forward, other going backwards). And you have a default `merge_mode` of `concat` meaning that the two output states from forward and backward layers will be concatenated. This gives you a `(None, 128)` sized output.

Comment: I added code. In this case, If I wanted to provide the input_shape, what will it be?

Comment: @ling, what's the size of your `train_data` set (i.e. size of every dimension)?